# makefile - how to link the objects in all subdirectory togother?

Tags: makefile

I'm writing a makefile framework for a project. Say, I have a main.c in the top dir, and many subdirs each containing a C file. To link all the object files togoter, I assign a initial value in the top makefile:

```
export TARGET_LIST := main.o
```

And in each subdirs, I append them to the list:

```
# sub1/Makefile
TARGET := a.o                                                                                                                                                          
TARGET_LIST += $(TARGET)
```

When return to the top dir, the TARGET_LIST is still with main.o. I'm sure all subdirs are entered. Is there any good way to do this?

The top makefile:

```
all: main

export TOP_DIR = $(shell pwd)
export TARGET_LIST := main.o
SUBDIRS := a b c d

CFLAGS := -Iinc

all:main

main:main.o subdirs
        cc $(TARGET_LIST) -o $@ $(CFLAGS)

subdirs: $(patsubst %, _dir_%, $(SUBDIRS))

$(patsubst %, _dir_%, $(SUBDIRS)) :
        $(MAKE) -C $(patsubst _dir_%, %, $@) $(TGT)
```

The Rules.make:

```
all:$(TARGET)

%.o:%.c
        @echo $(TARGET_LIST)
        $(CC) -c $^ -o $@ $(CFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS)
```

The subdir makefile:

```
TARGET := a.o
TARGET_LIST += $(TARGET)
CFLAGS := 
LDFLAGS := 

include $(TOP_DIR)/Rules.make
```

Comment: `export` is not a normal part of a `makefile`.  You might be able to do something if the top-level makefile reads each sub-directory makefile, but if the top-level makefile runs a new copy of `make`, there is no easy way for the new `make` to feed information back to the original makefile.

Comment: Is it possible for source files in different subdirs to have the same name, e.g. `sub1/a.c` and `sub2/a.c`?

Comment: Thanks Jonathan Leffler! I'm considering using include now.

Comment: For files with the same name in different directory, this is indeed a problem...Maybe we have to add the path to each object files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do yourself the favour, and use a high-level build system if you can. Almost anything is better than hand-written Makefiles. E.g. [CMake](http://cmake.org), [SCons](http://scons.org) or [waf](http://code.google.com/p/waf/) are some of the more popular alternatives.